Need help in using SQL split by delimeter, and get data from another table from the results of split data
I have 2 Tables
Table -1



Soltid
SlotName
Amount




1
Slot-1
100


2
Slot-2
150


3
Slot-3
150


4
Slot-4
125


5
Slot-5
100


6
Slot-6
100


7
Slot-7
150


8
Slot-8
125


9
Slot-9
100


10
Slot-10
150


11
Slot-11
150


12
Slot-12
125



Table -2



Bid
Bdate
SlotIds
Status




1
2024-06-16
1,2,3
Booked


2
2024-06-16
5
InProcess


3
2024-06-16
12
Blocked


4
2024-06-16
7,9
Booked



I want Details for each slotid like this based on dates as input
Result Expected



SlotId
SlotName
Bid
Status
Amount




1
Slot-1
1
Booked
100


2
Slot-2
1
Booked
150


3
Slot-3
1
Booked
150


4
Slot-4
NULL
Available
125


5
Slot-5
2
InProcess
100


6
Slot-6
NULL
Available
100


7
Slot-7
4
Booked
150


8
Slot-8
NULL
Available
125


9
Slot-9
4
Booked
100


10
Slot-10
NULL
Available
150


11
Slot-11
NULL
Available
150


12
Slot-12
3
Blocked
125



What I tried is:-
SELECT a.SlotId,a.SlotName,a.Amount,b.BId, isnull(b.[status],'Available') as [Status]   FROM Table-1 a right join Table-2 b on a.SlotId =b.SlotId and b.BookingDate='2024-06-23'

This works when slotid is inserted one by one in the column,Now I want to separate slotid by (,) comma, and then compare to get results.  - MS SQL SERVER

As far as I know the syntax and behavior of string split depends on the SQL server (for example MS SQL Server splits into rows, MySQL requires you to specify the position you're interested in). Unless you do ugly hacks with concatenation (see whether ",1,3,5," contains ",4," or not) you might want to specify better, or even look into a subtable Bid_Has_Slotid(Bid, Slotid), which would be more work, but in my opinion much cleaner, scalable and probably performant.

Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Please specify the RDBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) you are using, along with its version.

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or higher, then you can use SPLIT_STRING:
SELECT t1.Soltid, t1.SlotName, s.Bid, COALESCE(s.Status, 'Available') AS Status, t1.Amount
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Bid, Value AS Soltid, Status
  FROM table_2
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(SlotIds, ',')
) AS s ON s.Soltid = t1.Soltid

Demo here
